# Cannot Start JanusGraph as per documentation

Tags: tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am using the [Janus Graph doc](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/getting-started.html) and I extracted it as mentioned.

```
./gremlin.sh
```

works fine and it starts the Gremlin prompt.

This code also works fine

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('inmemory')
g = graph.traversal()
```

---

**Problem**

When I do this, I get a huge stacktrace

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje-es.properties')


gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje-es.properties')
12:15:49 WARN  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient  - Unable to determine Elasticsearch server version. Default to FIVE.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of JanusGraph 0.2.0, you cannot run Elasticsearch as an embedded node, so you need to start up an Elasticsearch node. You could download and deploy your own [Elasticsearch node](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch), or you could take advantage of the JanusGraph [pre-packaged distribution](http://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/server.html#_using_the_pre_packaged_distribution):

```
bin/janusgraph.sh start
```

This command will start up one Cassandra node, one Elasticsearch node, and a Gremlin Server. Note that you will need the Java Development Kit (JDK) to run this command.

Alternatively, you could start the only the Elasticsearch node from the JanusGraph pre-packaged distribution:

```
elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```

which will start Elasticsearch in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to run this command but i am getting this error
**jps command not found.  Put the JDK's jps binary on the command path.**

Comment: I also tried to change the JAVA_HOME  path but still got the same error.

Comment: The `jps` command is found in the Java Development Toolkit (JDK). If you have the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) only, you won't have that command available. I've updated my answer with the alternative of starting Elasticsearch only.